# Prime reversion algorithm does not work properly

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Consider the range 0 to 10. The primes in this range are: 2, 3, 5, 7, and thus the prime pairs are: (2,2), (2,3), (2,5), (2,7), (3,3), (3,5), (3,7),(5,5), (5,7), (7,7).

Let's take one pair (2,7) as an example and get the product, then sum the digits of the result as follows: 2 * 7 = 14, and 1 + 4 = 5. We see that 5 is a prime number. Similarly, for the pair (7,7), we get: 7 * 7 = 49, and 4 + 9 = 13, which is a prime number.

You will be given a range and your task is to return the number of pairs that revert to prime as shown above. In the range (0,10), there are only 4 prime pairs that end up being primes in a similar way: (2,7), (3,7), (5,5), (7,7). Therefore, solve(0,10) = 4)

Note that the upperbound of the range will not exceed 10000. A range of (0,10) means that: 0 <= n < 10.

I came up with this solution but it does not work in all cases. My code passes about 90 tests from 107 and I can not figure out what the problem could be.
For example: a: 94 b: 971 - it should return 3777 but instead i get 3834.

```
function isPrime(n) {
    if(n < 2){
        return false;
    }
    for (var i = 2; i <= parseInt(Math.sqrt(n)); i++) {
        if (n % i === 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function getPrimes(s, e) {
    var primes = [];
    for (var p = s; p <= e; p++) {
        if(isPrime(p)){
            primes.push(p);
        }
    }
    return primes;
}

function generatePairs(primes){
    var pairs = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < primes.length; i++){
        for(var j = i; j < primes.length; j++){
            pairs.push([primes[i], primes[j]]);
        }
    }
    return pairs;
}

function sumDigits(n){
    var sum = 0;
    while(n > 0){
        sum += n % 10;
        n = parseInt(n/10);
    }
    return sum;
}

function solve(a, b) {
    var pairs = generatePairs(getPrimes(a, b));
    var res = 0;
    for(pair of pairs){
        var tmp = sumDigits(pair[0] * pair[1]);
        if(isPrime(tmp)){
            res++;
        }

    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: why should `a: 94 b: 971` return `3777`?

Comment: You mention in your question that *A range of (0,10) means that: 0 <= n < 10.*, while your code also uses the upper bound. Could this be your problem?

Comment: @Glubus That is the exact problem :)

Comment: I saw you deleted the question on breaking sentences into words. I had prepared an answer. If you are still interested and undelete your question, I will post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @glubus mentioned in his comment above, your `b` is the **upper-bound** value, you need to pass `b-1` to the `getPrimes` method.

```
 var pairs = generatePairs(getPrimes(a, b-1));
```

Answer (score -1):

Without debugging it myself, here are some general ideas:

The basic idea of your (very straightforward) code seems to be correct (although the efficiency of it might leave something to be desired).

If the overall code is going wrong, it has to be going wrong in some particular place.

So you want to check that each stage is correct.

If your result is too high, and you are sure of that,
it suggests that some non-primes might be in your list of primes.
Either in the generation phase or the checking-the-final answer phase.
**Or your loops might be going slightly too far in some cases.**

Note that when comparing with the square root, you don't need the
integer form of square root. For example, sqrt(132) = 11.489... and
7 < 11.489 as well as 7 < 11.

My approach would be to find the smallest possible case that fails, and check all the intermediate stages by hand.  Or write some checking code.

If you are going to call "solve" repeatedly, you don't need to generate all the primes and pairs over and over (especially the primes) since they never change (or at least they haven't for a very long time).

Comment: This is not an anwer to OP's problem and should have been a comment.

Comment: @Glubus:I have added bold to the part of my answer which I believe DOES answer the OP's question, but without pointing out the specific line of code.

Comment: The point is that you spout around 10 different things, which makes it impossible to distill anything substantial from your post. The single line you made bold starts with "Or", implying  you aren't sure at all that this might be the case. If you're not sure that your answer fully solves the problem, then it is not an answer. Notice how in the comments I was very specific about what I suspected was the problem? That is the level of specificness you need in an answer. The reason I still commented it is because I wasn't sure, and I don't want to waste anyones time for some virtual points.